# How do you return selected values from two ListBoxes to an mvc controller using razor and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I want to return the selections from two ListBoxes back to my controller in C# MVC 4.5.1.  I've tried passing back the model:

```
<div class="report-modal-col">
        <div class="report-modal-titles">
            Select Worksite(s):
        </div>
        <br />
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedWorksites, Model.Worksites, new { size = 8 })
    </div>
    <div class="report-modal-col">
        <div class="report-modal-titles">
            Select Transaction(s):
        </div>
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedTransactions, Model.Transactions, new {size = 8})
    </div>
    <div class="report-btn-wrapper">
        @Html.ActionLink("GENERATE REPORT", "RunEnrollmentSummaryReport", "AdminTile", Model, new { id = "enrollmentSummaryReportLinky", @class="report-btn"}) <br/>

    </div>
```

with the corresponding controller method:

```
public ActionResult RunEnrollmentSummaryReport(AdminAdHocReportsTileViewModel model)
```

I've also tried sending back both lists separately, and also nothing (thinking the model would just miraculously populate itself).  I have successfully passed back one list selection using JSON, but not two sets of selections from two lists. Nothing yet works.  Any ideas?

Comment: How are you passing the model back to the controller?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: All you have shown is a link to s GET method which will not take into account anything you have edited. You need to submit a form.

Comment: put everything in Html.BeginForm and add a submit button   -@Html.BeginForm("ActionName","Controllername","FormMethod.Post/Get"){  <button type="submit" class=""  id=""  }

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this feedback.  I am trying it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@model ProjectName.Models.ModelName



  @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName"))
   {

<div class="report-modal-col">
    <div class="report-modal-titles">
        Select Worksite(s):
    </div>
    <br />
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedWorksites, Model.Worksites, new { size = 8 })
</div>
<div class="report-modal-col">
    <div class="report-modal-titles">
        Select Transaction(s):
    </div>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedTransactions, Model.Transactions, new {size = 8})
</div>


<button type="submit"> Submit</button>

   }
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The BeginForm extension was the key.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this.  I can offer you a solution to your problem of posting selections from multiple listboxes.  It uses the concept of a ViewModel.  You can follow this to get a working example to work off of and then refactor.

Start with the definition of the ViewModel.  Create the following:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel() {}

    // These are the options lists..
    public List<SelectListItem> ListItem1 { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ListItem2 { get; set; }

    // These are user selections..
    public List<string> SelectedListItems1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectedListItems2 { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, create a private method that we will use to load selections for your view model.

```
// the vwModel param is for reuse in our post later on..
private ViewModel LoadViewModel(ViewModel vwModel)
{
  if(vwModel == null)
    vwModel = new ViewModel();

  List<SelectListItem> List1 =
    new List<SelectListItem> {
      new SelectListItem { Text="list1-a", Value="list1-a" },
      new SelectListItem { Text="list1-b", Value="list1-b" },
      new SelectListItem { Text="list1-c", Value="list1-c" }
    }

  List<SelectListItem> List2 =
    new List<SelectListItem> {
      new SelectListItem { Text="list2-a", Value="list2-a" },
      new SelectListItem { Text="list2-b", Value="list2-b" },
      new SelectListItem { Text="list2-c", Value="list2-c" }
    }

  vwModel.ListItem1 = List1;
  vwModel.ListItem2 = List2;

  return vwModel;
}
```

Add a get to your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = LoadViewModel(null);
    LoadSelections();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

In you razor view (say Index.cshtml) here's how your declarative might look:

```
@model YourSolutionName.Models.ViewModel

@{
    using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
      @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedListItems1, new SelectList(Model.ListItems1, "Value", "Text"));
      @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedListItems2, new SelectList(Model.ListItems2, "Value", "Text"));

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
    <!- this is to display the post result of your selections.. -->
    <div>ListBox-&gt;
      <div>
        Selections List1: 
        @if(@ViewBag.ListBox1Selected != null)
        {
          foreach(var item in @ViewBag.ListBox1Selected)
          {
            <span>@item</span>@Html.Encode(",")
          }
        }
      </div>
      <div>
        Selections List2: 
        @if(@ViewBag.ListBox2Selected != null)
        {
          foreach(var item in @ViewBag.ListBox2Selected)
          {
            <span>@item</span>@Html.Encode(",")
          }
        }
      </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now we just need to code the post to put our example together:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel viewModel)
{
  // just some crude model state checking..
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     return View(ModelState.Values);
  }

  ViewBag.ListBox1Selected = viewModel.SelectedListItems1;
  ViewBag.ListBox2Selected = viewModel.SelectedListItems2;

  // just reusing our load helper method here passing in the viewModel obj
 //  from the post..
  var vwModel = LoadViewModel(viewModel);

  return View(viewModel);
}
```

That should be enough for you to get going with a working example that you can setup breakpoints on and inspect so you can understand how it's put together.

Also, you can refactor the HttpPost method my removing the ViewBag property assignments.  Since the selections can be obtained from the Model obj by the razor view on the post rendering.

So in the view you can swap out-
  @if(@ViewBag.ListBox1Selected != null)
for
  @if(Model.SelectedListItem1 != null)